# Кастомное модальное окно не по центру экрана

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qdialog, framelesswindowhint

Если не трогать оконные флаги у модального окна (оставить его рамочным), то всё отображается как нужно.

Но стоит поставить `FramelessWindowHint`, то окно уезжает куда то вправо вниз. И его видно если только растянуть основное окно.

Как можно оставить модальное окно безрамочным, но без проблем с отображением?

**answer1.py** *Основное окно*

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from answer2 import DialogUnpacking


class General(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(400, 150)

        self.general = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.general.setObjectName("general")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.general)

        self.btn_unpacking = QPushButton('Доп. окно', self)
        self.btn_unpacking.clicked.connect(self.modal_unpacking)

    def modal_unpacking(self):
        modalswin = DialogUnpacking(self)
        modalswin.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = General()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**answer2.py** *Модальное окно*

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class DialogUnpacking(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        # self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        modalgrid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)

        self.btn_unpack = QPushButton("Принять", self)
        self.btn_unpack.setFixedSize(150, 30)
        self.btn_unpack.clicked.connect(self.modalWinHide)
        modalgrid.addWidget(self.btn_unpack, 2, 0)

        self.btn_close = QPushButton("Отмена", self)
        self.btn_close.setFixedSize(150, 30)
        self.btn_close.clicked.connect(self.modalWinHide)
        modalgrid.addWidget(self.btn_close, 2, 1)

    def modalWinHide(self):
        self.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = DialogUnpacking()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
...
    def modal_unpacking(self):
        self.modalswin = DialogUnpacking()                 # - self
#        self.modalswin.show()
        self.modalswin.exec()
...
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Благодарю! Всё работает как надо!

Comment: @PandaStock не за что.